# How to deploy a WAR onto an existing Tomcat 6 instance using Cargo?

Tags: maven-2, tomcat6, pom.xml, cargo

I installed Tomcat using the Windows installer ages ago and it runs fine as a service on my development laptop. Now I'm mavenising my project and would like to use Cargo (or something similar) to deploy updated WARs onto the local Tomcat.

I can't find any fully worked examples of a POM file containing the right XML to do this and am struggling with the partial examples on the Cargo site.

Does anyone have a POM they can post or know of an example in the wild they can link to?

---

FWIW the error I get is this - though I've tried many different combinations of parameters:

> Cannot create configuration. There's
>   no registered configuration for the
>   parameters (container [id =
>   [tomcat6x], type = [local]],
>   configuration type [existing]).
>   Actually there are no valid types
>   registered for this configuration.
>   Maybe you've made a mistake spelling
>   it?

I'm not even sure I know exactly what the error means by a "type" in the first place!

**Update**: I eventually found the m2eclipse WTP integration plugin, which frankly rocks!

Comment: I eventually found the m2eclipse WTP integration plugin, which frankly rocks!

Comment: Can you please expand how you got them to work together as they are separate plugins.

Comment: Sorry, too long ago now. I recall only that there is a specific plugin for doing this and it relies on two separate plugins m2eclipse and WTP. I'd have just gone and found it on one of the update sites.

Comment: Simon: I think you should write the answer to your question inside and mark it *closed* for clarity

Comment: Asaf: none of the close reasons apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason to use just cargo?

You can try the maven tomcat plugin in order to deploy your wars to tomcat. See the instructions about [configuration](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/configuration.html) and [deployment](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/deployment.html).